# no operator "[]" matches these operands for a string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a `Graph` and an errors shows that there isn't a operand [] for string, but the documentation seems to say otherwise.

Here is my code, it shows the error at the function `addEdge`

```
class Graph
{

  list<string> *adj;
  void printAllPathsUtil(int, int, bool[], int[], int &);

public:
Graph();
  void addEdge(string u, string v);
  void printAllPaths(string s, string d);
};

Graph:: Graph()
{
  adj = new list<string>;
}

void Graph::addEdge(string u, string v)
{
  adj[u].push_back(v); // 
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated on how to solve this.

EDIT: Here is the full error
 `no operator "[]" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::__cxx11::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>> * [ std::string ]`

Comment: `adj` is not a string. It's a `list<string>*`. Did you mean for it to be a `list<string>`? It's a common problem to over-pointer everything when learning C++. As a general piece of advice, you probably shouldn't be using raw pointers (`some_type*`) at all starting out, and even as a veteran I try my best to stay away from them.

Answer (score 3):

`adj` is a pointer to a dynamically allocated `list` (why is it dynamic? That is not necessary).  But you are treating it like it were an array indexed by a string, which will never work.  You can't index a pointer/array using a string, only an integer.

If you want to store a list of values that are keyed by strings, use a `std::(unordered_)map` instead, ie:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>

class Graph
{
  std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> adj;
  ...

public:
  Graph() {}
  void addEdge(std::string u, std::string v);
  ...
};

void Graph::addEdge(std::string u, std::string v)
{
  adj[u].push_back(v); // <-- this works now!
}
```